# QListWidget item at 0th index is selected by default

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget which has some item, and I have "Remove" button on my form which actually removes item from list. Problem is that when form load for first time and I press remove without selecting any item from list, it takes the item at 0th index by default and remove it. Following is the code segment:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("Item1"));
    ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("Item2"));
    ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("Item3"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btnRemove_clicked()
{
    printf("on_btnRemove_clicked() \n");

    int currentRow = ui->listWidget->currentRow();
    QModelIndex currentIndex = ui->listWidget->currentIndex();
    QListWidgetItem* currentItem = ui->listWidget->currentItem();

    printf("currentRow: %d\n", currentRow);

    if(currentRow > -1) {
        printf("currentIndex.data() %s: \n", currentIndex.data().toString().toStdString().c_str());
        printf("currentItem->data(0): %s \n", currentItem->data(0).toString().toStdString().c_str());

        QListWidgetItem* itemToDelete = ui->listWidget->takeItem(currentRow);
        delete itemToDelete;
        itemToDelete = NULL;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to override this behavior or at least anyway that I can show that 0th index is selected  with default blue background of item.

Comment: If you have more than one focusable component on the form, then you can just set the focus of any component other than the QListWidget. It works for me at least.

Comment: One thing to note is that for QListWidgetItem's with checkboxes. If you click on the checkbox the currentRow() function in the slot SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)) returns an incorrect(?) value, in my case it always returns the value 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the selected item after adding the items, by calling setCurrentItem:-

```
QListWidgetItem* pSelectedItem = new QListWidgetItem("Item1");

ui->listWidget->addItem(pSelectedItem);
ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("Item2"));
ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("Item3"));

ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(pSelectedItem);
```

As the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) state: -

> *Unless the selection mode is NoSelection, **the item is also be selected**.*

Alternatively, rather than retrieving the current Item, get the selected items with [selectedItems()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems), which I would expect to return an empty list with which you can check the number of items: -

```
 if(ui->listWidget->selectedItems().count())
 {
     // delete items
 }
```

Note that a call to [clearSelection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection) states:-

> *Deselects all selected items. **The current index will not be changed.***

I would expect this means that requesting the current index or current item can return a valid index or item, which is why delete removes the item, even though it is not selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `setCurrentRow` from `QListWidget`:

```
// Set the first row as current
ui->listWidget->setCurrentRow(0);
```

and add a blue background color with:

```
// Get default background color
QBrush defaultBrush = ui->listWidget->currentItem->background();

// Set background color
QBrush brush(Qt::blue);
ui->listWidget->currentItem->setBackground(brush);
```

to set the default color:

```
// Change background color with default color
ui->listWidget->currentItem->setBackground(defaultBrush);
```

Comment: I think @gmuhammad meant that he wanted the selected item to be shown as selected which is blue by default, not to colour it in separately. By calling setCurrentRow, the item will be highlighted as selected, so there is no need to set its background colour too.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a many-years-old question, recently I came across a similar problem and solved the problem by overriding the behavior mentioned by the op. To help people who are dealing with the same problem but are not satisfied with the accepted answer, I'll post my alternative solution here.

I found the weird behavior comes from `QAbstractItemView::focusInEvent`.
As shown below by the snippet from Qt source code, when a `QListWidget` (or whatever widget that inherits `QAbstractItemView`) receives a non-mouse focus event, its first item becomes its current item automatically if there isn't a current item.

```cpp
// code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView12focusInEventEP11QFocusEvent
void QAbstractItemView::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    QAbstractScrollArea::focusInEvent(event);
    const QItemSelectionModel* model = selectionModel();
    bool currentIndexValid = currentIndex().isValid();
    if (model
        && !d->currentIndexSet
        && !currentIndexValid) {
        bool autoScroll = d->autoScroll;
        d->autoScroll = false;
        QModelIndex index = moveCursor(MoveNext, Qt::NoModifier); // first visible index
        if (index.isValid() && d->isIndexEnabled(index) && event->reason() != Qt::MouseFocusReason) {
            selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(index, QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate);
            currentIndexValid = true;
        }
        d->autoScroll = autoScroll;
    }
    if (model && currentIndexValid)
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, (currentIndex().flags() & Qt::ItemIsEditable));
    else if (!currentIndexValid)
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, false);
    d->viewport->update();
}
```

To override this behavior, make a subclass of `QListWidget` and override `focusInEvent()` along with `focusOutEvent()` in the subclass.

```cpp
virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override {
    // bypass QAbstractItemView::focusInEvent
    QAbstractScrollArea::focusInEvent(event);
}
virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override {
    // bypass QAbstractItemView::focusOutEvent
    QAbstractScrollArea::focusOutEvent(event);
}
```